# is it possible access neptune DB from local machine via ssh tunnel/port forward while neptune IAM DB authorization enabled?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-neptune

i am unable to connect to Neptune DB from local system via ssh-tunnel EC2(ec2 exists in same vpc as neptune db) where neptune DB connectivity is established when Neptune IAM DB authorization is enabled.

With disabling IAM DB authorization i can able to access neptune DB from local machine.I could not find enough documentation on this. Can someone please help.

Comment: How exactly are you trying to connect?

Comment: i am trying to connect to neptune db from local laptop with ssh-tennel to a ec2 instance in the same VPC as neptune DB and ec2 instance does have connectivity to neptune DB. Now with IAM DB disable, i can able to run query against neptune DB from my local laptop with ssh tunneling where localhost:8082 is pointed to 8182:<neptune end point>:8182 in ec2 instance and query execution is getting success.
ssh tunnel step:

But with IAM DB authorization enable, query execution is getting failed with error "BadRequestException" from local with ssh tunneling.

Comment: Ssh tunnel creation query from local:

ssh -L 8182:<neptune end point>:8182 -i neptune.pem ec2user@IP

However , if i run query from the ec2 instance against the neptune DB with IAM enable, its getting success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using an SSH tunnel and using localhost in your connection string, you'll need to modify whatever IAM SigV4 process you're using to make sure the host header matches the Neptune cluster endpoint.  Otherwise, you'll be attempting to sign the request using localhost as the host and the signature will be invalid.

Comment: Do you have details on how to achieve this?

Comment: @Taylor Riggan, any details on how to achieve your suggestion?

Comment: Whatever library you're using to create the SigV4 Authorization signature (or if you just wrote your own), you would need to submit the request for signing with the host header modified to match your cluster endpoint.

Comment: If you want to get deep into the signing process, the following provides code that generates the proper signature for Neptune.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/iam-auth-connecting-python.html