# Can't access Amazon Neptune via SSH tunnel Sigv4

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-neptune, sigv4

I'm trying to access Neptune cluster `status` endpoint from an SSH tunnel. I can hit it without issue on my bastion host, but when doing via ssh tunnel, I get:

*https://localhost:8182/status*

```
{"detailedMessage":"Bad request.","requestId":"random-request-id-appears-here","code":"BadRequestException"}
```

How can I do this? It seems like I need something with sigv4. I was hoping to see the response work after hitting this in my browser.

I've *also* tried `awscurl` after setting my env variables, I get:

```
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=8182): Max retries exceeded with url: /status (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError("hostname 'localhost' doesn't match either of '*.id.us-east-2.neptune.amazonaws.com', '*.id.us-east-2.neptune.amazonaws.com', '*.cluster-custom-id.us-east-2.neptune.amazonaws.com', '*.cluster-ro-id.us-east-2.neptune.amazonaws.com'")))
```

Comment: Please see the answer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66349364/is-it-possible-access-neptune-db-from-local-machine-via-ssh-tunnel-port-forward

Comment: @KelvinLawrence I still can't this to work with ssh tunneling. How is it possible to get it to work hitting in browser?

Comment: As shown in the answer below your best bet is to use something like awscurl as if IAM is enabled and you are using SigV4 then the request will need to be signed. Without something like an additional plugin a browser will not know how to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using SSH tunnel for accessing Neptune using localhost, one need to explicitly pass Neptune endpoint as host header for signing the request. Consider below example for awscurl:

```
awscurl -k --service neptune-db --access_key $ACCESS_KEY --secret_key $SECRET_KEY --region <neptune_instance_region> --session_token $SESSION_TOKEN --header 'host: <neptune-cluster-endpoint-withouthttp-withoutport>' https://localhost:8182/status
```

Without the explicit host header, request would be signed using "localhost" with an invalid signature.